# when linking to a specific address, I want it to go to root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want this url:

http://www.example.com/en/

to redirect to:

http://www.example.com

can this be done in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

In the `/en/` directory's htaccess file, you can add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ / [L,R]
```

Or in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/$ / [L,R]
```

Comment: ok but if something is following the /en/ i dont want that to redirect. Only if the url is exactly http://www.example.com/en/ or http://www.example.com/en

Comment: @pwneth yes, the `$` character ensures that's the *end* of the URI.

Comment: ok well for some reason this redirects me to example.com even if its example.com/en/example